# How to get notes from certain notebooks in Evernote Javascript API

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote

I my Node.Js app I need to filter the notes that I extract using

```
findNotesMetadata
```

so that it only extracts the notes from the notebooks with certain GUIDs.

I know I can use

```
noteFilter
```

to do that.

But can I pass several notebook IDs to it? And How?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You will need call findNotesMetadata for each notebook.

Here is some sample code that retrieves all the notes from the default notebook and logs the titles of the notes:

```
  Evernote = require('evernote').Evernote;

  var authToken = "your developer token";

  if (authToken == "your developer token") {
    console.log("Please fill in your developer token");
    console.log("To get a developer token, visit https://sandbox.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action");
    process.exit(1);
  }

  var client = new Evernote.Client({token: authToken, sandbox: true});

  var userStore = client.getUserStore();
  var noteStore = client.getNoteStore();

  var notebook=noteStore.getDefaultNotebook(function (err, notebook){
    //create filter for findNotesMetadata
    filter = new Evernote.NoteFilter();
    //set the notebook guid filter to the GUID of the default notebook
    filter.notebookGuid = notebook.guid;
    //create a new result spec for findNotesMetadata
    resultSpec = new Evernote.NotesMetadataResultSpec();
    //set the result spec to include titles
    resultSpec.includeTitle=true;
    //call findNotesMetadata on the note store
    noteStore.findNotesMetadata(filter, 0, 100, resultSpec, function(err, notesMeta) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('err',err);
        }
        else {
          //log the number of notes found in the default notebook
          console.log("Found "+notesMeta.notes.length+" notes in your default notebook . . .")
          for (var i in notesMeta.notes) {
            //list the title of each note in the default notebook
            console.log(i+": "+notesMeta.notes[i].title);
          }


        }}); 

  });
```

sample output:

```
  Found 3 notes in your default notebook . . .
  0: This is a test note!
  1: Hello Developer Forums!!!
  2: How are you doin'?
```